# Redirect from one WebAPI to an another WebAPI and getting the response

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I want to create lets say a master/core api.Want to check for a certain parameter value and redirect to a an external api hosted in the same server.I have an api with uri http://hello.test.com/auth which takes two auth params Username and Password.Now i add a third parameter lets say Area.

```js
{
"Username":"jason",
"Password":"bourne",
"Area":"mars"
}
```

Now coming to the master api, if with this uri for example http://master.test.com/v1/mster and i pass Username, Password and Area,and if the Area has value of lets say "mars" it should call the external mars api having uri http://mars.test.com/auth ,do the auth the process and return the response in the master api.is this possible?

With my /auth api i have this controller returning the response :

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route(ApiEndpoint.AUTH)]
    public HttpResponseMessage Auth(Login authBDTO)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);

        using (AccountBusinessService accountService = new AccountBusinessService())
        {
            var result = accountService.Auth(authBDTO);
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);
        }
    }
```

Any Help Appreciated.Couldnt find this exact scenario in here.Sorry if too naive.

Comment: Yes, your controller could issue an HTTP call to another API and return the response. So you could do that. But why do you want to?

Comment: @CodeCaster sir,there are multiple apis for different customers which is consumed by a mobile client.So instead of creating individual app for different customer,i want lets say a dropdown list in the said mobile app with username,password and AREA.area will define the said api in my server.so if the request comes with "mars" value for the area, i want to call the api from http://mars.test.com/auth and return the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a workaround.This did the work.

```
    [Route(ApiEndpoint.SAS)]
    public IHttpActionResult esp(Login auth)
    {
        if (auth.Coop == "PMC")
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:60069/api/v1/auth");
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
                {
                    Username = auth.UserName,
                    Password = auth.Password
                });

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {

                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(result);
                obj.BaseUrl = "http://localhost:60069/api/v1";

                return Ok(obj);

            }

        }
```